# Couldn't upload the path of images laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i am begineer of laravel 8. when i tried to upload the images it uploaded successfully. go to path and check it images are there. but in database path didn't save i don't why. when i uploaded the images path saved in the database like this **C:\xampp\tmp\phpD096.tmp**

what it the code which tried on so far i attched below.

**Form**

```
 <form action="{{ url('contact') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">>
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <label>Name</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"></br>
        <label>Address</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></br>
        <label>Mobile</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control"></br>

        <input class="form-control" name="photo" type="file" id="photo">

        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"></br>
    </form>
```

**ContactController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $fileName = time().$request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('images', $fileName, 'public'); 
    $requestData["photo"] = '/storage/'.$path;

    Contact::create($input);
    return redirect('contact')->with('flash_message', 'Contact Addedd!');  
}
```

Comment: No need to store full path
use https://intervention.io/

Comment: i want to retrieve images so path i need store on the database

Comment: you can use asset() when need to retrive. <img src="{{asset($company->company_logo)}}" alt="{{$company->name}}">

Comment: <img src="{{ asset($item->photo) }}" width= '50' height='50' class="img img-responsive" />

Comment: i used but no images showned

Comment: case u save full path on DB, No need to save full path, save only foldername and file name

Comment: Like images/20220206095104-logo10.png

Comment: how to do the task i attached above how i saved the images

Comment: you are creating this `$requestData` array and not doing anything with it ... I am assuming you mean to be setting `$input['photo']` instead